# When click on button I am not able to search item from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I type something in textbox and when I click on search button it shows the item

[image]

When click on button I am not able to search item from list.
I am able to search item directly without click on button, but I want to search item when

```js
this.state = {
  list: [],
  search: '',
}

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/africa").then(res=> 
    {
        this.setState({list : res.data})
    })
}
 
<label className="text-secondary">Search by : </label>&nbsp;
                
<input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.valueChange}> 
</input>&nbsp;

valueChange = (event) =>{
    this.setState({search : event.target.value})       
}
  
          
<button type="button" className="btn btn-info" 
   onClick=this.search}>Search</button>

search = () =>{
   this.state.list.filter(
        (item) => {
            return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
            item.capital.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
            item.alpha3Code.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: provide more code that renders, because this shown code doesnt contain any UI elements such as input and so on...

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is to move the search logic into a function and set the onclick listener to trigger this function.

Something like this:

```
function SomeComponent(props){
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  const handler = () => {
    // Put your search logic here
    alert(`Do the search by ${keyword}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={keyword} onInput={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handler}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: kindly please check my updated code...I tried what you say but I didn't get any output...

Comment: You will need to implement the render function which return your layout if you are using class component.